# Access to 389 directory server console on fedora

Tags: fedora, gui, active-directory

I installed 389 directory server and Java on Fedora server but 389-console said I need X Windows system. The problem is fedora server come with no GUI.

- Do I need to install X Window system on fedora server? or
- I need to totally move 389 directory server to fedora workstation which comes with Gnome?

  `No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it. at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironme‌​nt.java:204) at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:536) at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420) at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385) at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:189) at com.netscape.management.client.console.Console.<init>(Unknow‌​n Source) at com.netscape.management.client.console.Console.main(Unknown Source)`

Answer (score 2):

If installing X on that server is not an option, SSH into it from a workstation that has X running, and tunnel the X connection with the '-X' argument to `ssh`. Then run "389-console" in the remote session, and you should get the console window on the workstation.

Comment: This.  Any linux machine - boot from a livecd if you need to.  Or Mac you can install a X server from the Store.  On Windows there are pay-for ones but I recommend cygwin-x.  Note you may need to install the xauth package on the remote box